# How is robust terminal emulation achieved in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, keyboard, emulation

My question is using only Ubuntu and/or open source components, how is full terminal emulation with keyboard mapping, logging, and printing achieved in Ubuntu without purchasing a product? By using the term terminal emulation, I am referring to having keys that are mapped to functions, and behave in a couple of but not limited to two standard cases, a VT100 or standard Unix/Linux terminal.

I have very good terminal emulation in Ubuntu, because I went out and purchased VanDyke's [SecureCrt](http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/unix.html) for Linux. My customers use the Windows version of VanDyke's SecureCrt, and I also need it on Linux.

However, I have to believe there is another to do keyboard remapping and obtain some, if not all, other things an emulator provides without purchasing a product.

If so, where does an end-user turn to achieve terminal emulation?

Comment: Question is entirely unclear, at least to someone who is not familiar with this program.  You need to be specific about what you are looking for.

Comment: Edited OP with a brief explanation. SecureCrt is a brand of terminal emulator available from VanDyke.

Answer (score 1):

Try [terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/)?

- Free? ✓
- Logging? ✓
- Key binding? ✓

etc, etc....